# Reference a row cell with multiple column cells and return the sum of intersection result

Tags: excel, match

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib5lJ.png)

```
ID        AY    Score       2012    2013    2014    2015    2016    2017    2018

400024  2013    70.1875        0       1       0       0       0       0       0
400025  2015    3.0625         0       0       0       2       0       0       0
400028  2016    9.0625         0       1       0       0       0       0       0
400033  2013    50.625         0       1       0       0       0       0       0
```

What I want to do is compare each cell of AY  with column for same year and next two years, then return sum of intersections.

For example, for second data row (400025), it should compare 2015 with column 2015, 2016 and 2017 and then return result 2+0+0 = 2

For third data row (400028), it should compare 2016 with column 2016, 2017 and 2018 and then return result 0+0+0 = 0

Comment: Recomendation; Google offset and match. You should be able to figure it from there. If you have problems making it work update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Sum with INDEX and MATCH:

```
=SUM(INDEX(D2:J2,MATCH(B2,$D$1:$J$1,0)):INDEX(D2:J2,MATCH(B2,$D$1:$J$1,0)+2))
```

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you have done a resize with OFFSET instead of doing two index/matches?

Comment: Offset is volatile and I avoid volatile functions when non volatile functions will do the job.